# Cypress. cy.type({enter} fails intermittently

Tags: cypress

I am running e2e tests on a web app using Cypress.

This section fails intermittently.

Here, search text is entered in the appropriate field. When {enter} is clicked, the search happens & the dialog only shows the search results.

Here is the code:

```
  function selectDesign(designName: string, designCode: string) {

  // enter search text & click enter

  cy.get(singlePickerSearch).type(designName + '{enter}', { force: true });

  // select your design from search results

  cy.get(designPickerDesign(designCode))
    .scrollIntoView()
    .should('have.length', 1)
    .click({ force: true });
}
```

When it fails, it is like '{enter}' was not executed. I can click enter manually, and it works.

Because it is an intermittent failure, it is difficult to obtain logs.

Every single test uses the same design. In a single run there are 19 tests.  The test runner can find the file 18 times & then fail on 1 test.

Also tried using backticks in the .type() command:

```
cy.get(singlePickerSearch)
  .clear()
  .type(`${designName}{enter}`);
```

There was no appreciable improvement.

Comment: Note sure what this means - "It works fine with items starting with 'A'. By the time we get to 'S' the results become erratic.". Also, would be good if you could add some console logs if you see any errors.

Comment: @Kondasamy Jayaraman - that particularly suspicion turned out to be untrue, so I have removed it from the description of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working by using the following:

```
 function selectDesign(e2eDesign: any) {
//  open dodi picker
cy.get(createCardQueryOpenDodiPicker)
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()
  .then(() => {
    // wait for loader
    cy.get(loader).should('not.be.visible');
    // enter search text
    cy.get(dodiPickerSearchText)
      .clear()
      .type(`${e2eDesign.design.name}{enter}`)
      .then(() => {
        // wait for loader to go
        cy.get(loader).should('not.be.visible');
        // short wait to avoid intermittent failure here
        cy.wait(400);
        // select required design
        cy.get(dodiPickerItems)
          .should('have.length', 1) // should only be one match
          .click();
      });
  });
```

}

I think the last .should('have.length' 1) causes it to wait until that is true before trying to execute the next statement.